# Dissimilarity in Clustering

Tags: r, clustering, standardization

In clustering data you normally choose a dissimilarity measure such as euclidean and find a clustering method which best suits your data and each method has several algorithms which can be applied. For example, lets say I want to use hierarchical clustering, with the maximum distance measure and single linkage algorithm.

This is my understanding so far to how you would cluster data in a statistical software such as R.

In my case I have constructed my own dissimilarity matrix via `ks.boot` in R to calculate p-values for all my studies so 10 studies would generate a 10x10 matrix of p-values. I then subtracted 1 from each p-value and covered this matrix into a distance object. I used `hclust` to cluster my data using `single, average and complete` algorithms.

```
data <- read.csv(file="Data.csv",header=TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
mat <- outer(1:30, 1:30, Vectorize(function(i,j)
{ks.boot(as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[i,]))),
 as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[j,]))))$ks.boot.pvalue}))
d=as.dist(as.matrix(1-mat))
hc1_c <- hclust(d,method = "complete")
hc1_a <- hclust(d,method = "average")
hc1_s <- hclust(d,method = "single")
plot(hc1_c)
plot(hc1_a)
plot(hc1_s)
```

I'm slightly confused with:

1. Standardisation\transformation of data and why it's necessary. And where did I standardise my data. Maybe when I converted the matrix into an object?
2. Whats the name of the method I have used as a dissimilarity measure and how are p-values a viable method for calculating distances between objects. i.e why would you use a K-S test or AD/Cramer-von p value as a measure of distance.
3. How can I visualise the uncertainty in clustering and compare which algorithm (single, average, complete) clusters my data the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Standardization is not necessary. It is often better than not standardizing when you have attributes of different scale. But it a heuristic, not a must. You use his *before* computing distances, so it does not apply in your use case.
2. You don't need a name for this. It's just a distance matrix. You would not even need the 1-p transformation *if* you used an implementation of Single-Link for similarity rather than for distance functions (the same algorithm can be implemented for similarities, too).
3. Uncertainty here will not be reliable. You'd need much more data to quantify uncertainty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my 2nd question, can you recommend me any books or papers which talk the methodology behind my distance matrix? And I'm guessing the p-value matrix is a measure of similarity and 1-p is distance? Also for my third question, if not for my data then in general, how would you assess uncertainty. Especially when data involves different sample sizes